# No packages were pushed - Appveyor Nuget feed

Tags: c#, nuget, yaml, nuget-package, appveyor

this is my yml file:

```
deploy:
  - provider: NuGet
    symbol_server: https://ci.appveyor.com/nuget/xxxxx/api/v2/package
    api_key:
    secure: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    artifact: DataParser.1.0.0.nupkg
```

The nupkg file is located in the root of the solution (same directory of the .sln file)

However I get a warning on Appveyor:

> no packages were pushed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuget deployment provider assumes that artifact is packaged according to https://www.appveyor.com/docs/packaging-artifacts/.

Please ensure your appveyor.yml `artifacts:` section is properly configured, and build job log indicates that artifacts are packaged.

Also I recommend use **named** artifacts and use artifact name rather than file name in Nuget deployment settings.

--ilya.